# Is a Web Service Runtime available in .Net Core

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-core, filenet-p8, filenet

My team has written maintains a library that wraps functionality around a full framework .net .dll, specifically the IBM FileNet.Api.dll. We have been transitioning our library to use .net Standard and so far, all is well. After creating a .net core app and attempting to connect to FileNet, we run into a web service runtime problem.

Here is the error that is thrown:

> The operation cannot be completed because a supported web service
> runtime is not present. Either Microsoft Web Services Extensions (WSE)
> 3.0 or the Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) is required.

Does anyone know of a NuGet package that provides this runtime for .net Core or a workaround for this issue?

Comment: From AdeyG *There is a thread on an IBM Community group that suggests there might be support for .NET 6.0.

I have posted a question to ask if there are anymore updates.

Sorry this isn't really an answer but hopefully IBM will provide an update soon.

https://community.ibm.com/community/user/automation/discussion/filenet-api-support-for-aspnet-core*

Comment: While CoreWCF allows creating SOAP services with WCF, almost all services use REST/HTTP nowadays. Googling for `FileNet REST` or `FileNet WebHook` shows there are REST API and WebHook (essentially an HTTP callback) options

Answer (score 0):

Updade:
I have now had several conversations with the engineer team at IBM and they do not support .NET Core, nor do they plan on supporting it at this time. What I am doing is to create a .NET Framework 4.x API to basically convert to and from FileNet. It's a bit janky but when the customer wants their API in .NET Core I'm having to build something to make it work.

I'm running into the same issue. From what I've discovered System.Web.Services which is used by the FileNet.Api.dll and IBM's CEWSI for creating SOAP connections has been deprecated after .NET Framework 4.x in favor of WCF and is not available in .NET Core, .NET Standard, nor .NET 5.

It also appears that Microsoft is pushing developers to use REST instead of SOAP. I have not found anything from IBM to replace the DLL or CEWSI.

Sorry this isn't more useful, I'm still trying to figure out how to use .NET Core with it as well and short of basically recreating the functionality myself I haven't found a viable solution.

Comment: And what about the old COM apis, how are you mapping those calls to .net core ?

Comment: Have you found any solution yet?

Comment: same issue here. has anybody find a solution to this?